# mwl-calendar doesn't work with a directive

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I create a directive in angularjs to change the text in my angular month view but when I switch my view from week to go back to month it doesn't show my data.

```
<script id="customMonthCell.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div size-elt class="cal-month-day {{day.cssClass}}">
        <span
            class="pull-right"
            data-cal-date
            ng-click="vm.calendarCtrl.dateClicked(day.date)"
            ng-bind="day.label">
        </span>

        <small style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; left: 5px">{{monthCalendarDayDivWidth}}
            <div style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-repeat="(petitTitle, events) in day.groups track by petitTitle">
                <span ng-if="events.length > 1 && monthCalendarDayDivWidth > 130">               
                    {{events[0].description}}
                </span>
                <span ng-if="events.length > 1 && monthCalendarDayDivWidth <= 130">               
                    {{littleTitle}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </small>
    </div>
</script>



tabs.directive('sizeElt', ['$window', function ($window) {

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
            scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
            scope.monthCalendarDayDivWidth = element[0].offsetWidth
            scope.$apply();
        });
        angular.element($window).bind('load', function () {
            scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
            scope.monthCalendarDayDivWidth = element[0].offsetWidth
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}]);
```

This is when I load my page

[image]

this is when I click to week view and come back to month view

[image]

It's like monthCalendarDayDivWidth is not defined but if I force it when I switch the view it still doesn't work

```
$scope.monthCalendarDayDivWidth = $scope.windowWidth > 1080 ? 140 : 110
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify my directive so when I switch the view in my calendar I the data can be visible

```
tabs.directive('sizeElt', ['$window', function ($window) {

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A'
    };

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
            scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
            scope.monthCalendarDayDivWidth = element[0].offsetWidth
            scope.$apply();
        });

        if (element.offsetWidth !== 0 || element.offsetHeight !== 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;
                scope.monthCalendarDayDivWidth = element[0].offsetWidth
                scope.$apply();
            }, 0);
        }
    }
}]);
```